What is the fastest decompressing lossless file format to use in Blender?
Blender supports a variety of different texture formats, and I've mostly been using TIFF as it works better for normal maps. However, I've noticed with formats like PNG that the decompression process to load the raw pixel data into VRAM takes significantly more time between formats, something I have to take into account with large textures.
Formats like DDS are made to be decompressed by GPUs- what would an equilavent be for Blender? As far as I know, Blender uses OpenGL (and soon Vulkan), which has no "native" texture implementation- so everything still has to be converted into a format it recognizes?

I think you will need to test it if you want to find out. See this answer though. It may be that the bottleneck is reading from storage, not converting, so it may as well be that the smallest file size may be best for this. I would guess that PNG is probably not what you want to use though and that EXR might be a good choice.

In my experience, EXR is (or can be, depends on the codec) lightning fast compared to PNG, both in writing and reading. If you need an EXR viewer, DJV is amazing, especially good for image sequences (free, Windows).
